# OpenCV RAW to RGB conversion resulting in incorrect elemSize and depth

Tags: c++, opencv

When using OpenCV RAW to RGB conversion (CV_BayerBG2BGR), the image is displayed correctly but the image basic types are incorrect (elemSize & depth).

Even writing the converted Mat to file and then loading it (rgb_path in code below), there is a discrepancy between the loaded rgb image and the converted rgb image, although both display fine.

This causes an issue downstream where I convert from Mat to uint8_t* as the buffer size is larger in the converted rgb image.

Is this an issue with the conversion itself or my understanding of the conversion / OpenCV basic data types? I am using OpenCV 341.

```
int main() {

    Mat img = imread(rgb_path);

    ifstream ifd(raw_path, ios::binary | ios::ate);
    int size = ifd.tellg();
    ifd.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    vector<char> buffer;
    buffer.resize(size);
    ifd.read(buffer.data(), size);

    Mat rgb_image;
    Mat raw_image(600, 800, CV_16UC1, buffer.data());

    cvtColor(raw_image, rgb_image, CV_BayerBG2BGR);

    cout << "elemSize() orig: " << img.elemSize() << endl;
    cout << "elemSize() conv: " << rgb_image.elemSize() << endl;
    cout << "channels() conv: " << rgb_image.channels() << endl;
    cout << "channels() orig: " << img.channels() << endl;
    cout << "depth() conv: " << rgb_image.depth() << endl;
    cout << "depth() orig: " << img.depth() << endl;
    cout << "total() orig: " << img.total() << endl;
    cout << "total() conv: " << rgb_image.total() << endl;

    return 0;

}

Output:
elemSize() orig: 3
elemSize() conv: 6
channels() conv: 3
channels() orig: 3
depth() conv: 2
depth() orig: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue related to bitness of converted image still in 16bit format, where I was expecting 8bit. Resolved by adding:

```
Mat rgb_image8u;
rgb_image.convertTo(rgb_image8u, CV_8UC3, 1.0/255);
```

after line:

```
cvtColor(raw_image, rgb_image, CV_BayerBG2BGR);
```